# Using Tortoise SVN with C++ in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, tortoisesvn

I have an online repository with some .h and .cpp files that make up part of a project. I'm trying to check these out and use them in a new project, but am getting errors (C4627 and C1010). All the files have been added to the project (with Add>Existing Item...), and the subdirectories that contain these files have been added to the "Additional include directories" of the project.

Would I be better off having the entire project tree in the repository? My reason for not doing so is that my colleague and I are working on different parts of the code and so want to use different main methods to test things as we go, and I didn't see any need to be passing around any compiled code etc. since I assumed that given the .h and .cpp files (with the correct settings), visual studio would be able to compile the project.

What's the best way to make Visual Studio 2008 and TortoiseSVN work well together (without spending any money)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would I be better off having the entire project tree in the repository?

Most certainly yes.  You should be able to check out and build without much effort.  Creating a new project every time you want to build the source and having to configure it is way too much work.

> My reason for not doing so is that my colleague and I are working on different parts of the code and so want to use different main methods to test things as we go, and I didn't see any need to be passing around any compiled code etc.

Ok, just put more than one project in the solution.  There's no reason you can't have separate executable projects for separate tests.

> I assumed that given the .h and .cpp files (with the correct settings), visual studio would be able to compile the project.

If all of the settings are the same, then, yes, it should compile fine, but why bother with the hassle when you don't have to?

Comment: After having a look at things and messing about a bit I've found that excluding the debug directories and the Intellisense databases (.ncb files) from the repository can save some space and bandwidth. For this project it isn't all that much, but it's still something. As far as I'm aware these can just be rebuilt by VS with no trouble at all.

I also had a poke around and discovered the xml structure of projects, which was interesting (I was wondering how they could be easily merged by Tortoise, and found my answer there)

Answer (score 0):

> What's the best way to make Visual Studio 2008 and TortoiseSVN work well together (without spending any money)?

There are a bunch of programs that integrate SVN into Visual Studio. VisualSVN is one of them.

- Apologies for the VisualSVN recommendation. We used to use it in an old project and I'm positive it was free then. Maybe they changed their license?

Comment: VisualSVN costs $49, which is infinity times the amount stated in the question (zero).

Neeearly a downvote because this answer wastes my time looking into something that the context suggests is a free tool (i.e. you've proposed it just after pasting my "without spending any money" question). I suggest modifying this answer to make it clear that you are suggesting a non-free tool (a link to the website wouldn't hurt either).

Comment: Perhaps it was, I'm not sure - it would make sense if it was successful that they might have started charging (it puzzles me that they would wipe out a bunch of their potential clients by setting the price at $49 though)

Answer (score 0):

Also [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) which isn't too bad and it's free.  Also, lots of the windows it displays look like TFS (if you're familiar with it)

Comment: What does TFS stand for then?